# Why is crontab executing on one server but not the other?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, mysql

I have two servers on linode that have some websites on them. I created a script to see if mysql is running on the server and if it's not running then the script will start mysql. The script is on both servers and in the same file structure.

I have added the script to cron using the "crontab -e" command with both servers. The problem is my dev server will run the script while the prod server will stay down. I have added spaces to the end of the crontab so I know that isn't the problem.

When the script is run manually on the prod server I get this error "(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)". Even though the error shows up the script still restarts mysql but when the script is executing with cron, mysql will not restart. Also note that I have run the script on the dev server and managed to get the same error. Even though the error is there, the script will run on dev and restart mysql when run through cron.

When I run a command under sudo on the dev server it doesn't ask for the pass but when I run it on the prod server I get asked for a password.

I have checked syslog so I know that the cron command is running.

The script uses the netstat command with the parameters -v -u -l -n -t -p.

Comment: This is an aside, but when you have the time, it'd be a good idea to look into some form of [process supervision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision) tool instead of cobbling together something with cron.

Answer (score 0):

> When I run a command under sudo on the dev server it doesn't ask for the pass but when I run it on the prod server I get asked for a password

Have you compared sudo config on both nodes? Please run on both machines this command (from the account where you have modified crontab):

```
sudo -l
```

Answer (score 0):

several things to look at

run visudo as root and see if the user is listed there 
Should be something like (your user where username is)

username        ALL=(ALL)      NOPASSWD: ALL

This will let you sudo up w/o passwd.  If not there add it and then try your script again.

Now if it still not run as a cron it sounds like the cron entry is correct but possibly the script is not. It seems like your crons are firing from what you wrote you saw it in syslogs. 
try chmod 755 /path/to/script.sh

Let cron job run again.

If it stil doesn't run check the owner of the script. 
chown username /path/to/script.sh

Let us know if this helps.